# Voltage-controlled current source with gain limit

Tags: amplifier, current-source

I'm trying to design an amplifier circuit that acts as a voltage-controlled current source. I have found some topologies online that uses a shunt resistor together with active feedback and this is fine for the implementation.

I was wondering however whether it would be possible at all to design such a circuit with a voltage gain limit. This circuit would then limit the current if the voltage reaches a certain value.

Important to note is that it concerns an AC signal with a frequency of around 87.5 kHz.

The circuit should then have the following requirements:

1. A voltage amplitude of 2V at the input should represent a 160mA with a linear transfer.
2. If the output voltage reaches above 2V the gain should be limited to 1. So the output amplitude should stay 2V regardless if the current has reached 160mA.

I realize that clipping would be some sort of solution for this problem, but I was wondering whether you could do this in a way that the output would not be distorted?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Indeed, clipping is the standard way to do this. *do this in a way that the output would not be distorted?* If you change the gain abruptly (realize that a limiter has gain = 0 when clipping!) then your signal will **always** distort. If you want to attenuate your signal such that it never exceeds a threshold without affecting the shape of the waveform then you might want to look at "compression". I mean, a gain that gradually varies with signal amplitude.

Comment: Does that mean Vp=+/-160mA and goes thru 0 at Vp=2V ac or dc?  i.e. a VCCC for AC

Comment: Yeah ofcourse it would be distorted because a change in the shape of the waveform is unavoidable. And I would assume that clipping would be unavoidable in the beginning since the amplifier can not predict that it will go over the 1V. But might there be a way in which a feedback circuit would detect this clipping and can bring the gain back to where it wouldn't clip?

Comment: Yes indeed Vp= +/-160mA which is outputted at 2Vp at 0volt it should output 0mA.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a voltage source with a 12.5 ohm output impedance into a short circuit load or a current sensed feedback loop with limiting on peak, average or RMS.

Not enough info on load, THD, BW or AGC response time or tolerances on current.

Comment: Current doesn't have be very exact efficiency is more important. Load is a transformer where the load on the secondary side is resistive and very variable. Response time would need to be below ~0.1ms. The current sensed feedback loop with limiting on peak sounds promising how would one go about implementing this?

Comment: Sense DC current on primary centre tap with Voltage controlled DC to limit current  with AC on biphase differential input. I.e. an efficient buck regulator with current sensing but low source impedance as a voltage regulator to drive 12.5 Ohms minimum